# Asp.Net Core MVC Calculator

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am making a calculator on Asp.Net Core Mvc and ran into a problem. I have `CalcModel` and `CalcController`. Also the `IndexCalculator` view.

```
public class CalcModel
    {
    
        public decimal FirstNumber { get; set; }
        public decimal SecondNumber { get; set; }
        public decimal Result { get; set; }
        public CalculationMethod calculationMethod { get; set; }
    
        public enum CalculationMethod
        {
            [Display(Name = "+")]
            Addition,
            [Display(Name = "-")]
            Subtraction,
            [Display(Name = "*")]
            Multiplication,
            [Display(Name = "/")]
            Division
        }
    }
```

My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> IndexCalculator(CalcModel model)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            switch (model.calculationMethod)
            {
                case CalculationMethod.Addition:
                    model.Result = model.FirstNumber + model.SecondNumber;
                    break;
                case CalculationMethod.Subtraction:
                    model.Result = model.FirstNumber - model.SecondNumber;
                    break;
                case CalculationMethod.Multiplication:
                    model.Result = model.FirstNumber * model.SecondNumber;
                    break;
                case CalculationMethod.Division:
                    model.Result = model.FirstNumber / model.SecondNumber;
                    break;
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

And a my wiev:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("IndexCalculator", "Calc", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstNumber) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstNumber)<br />
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SecondNumber) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SecondNumber)<br />
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Result) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Result)<br />
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.calculationMethod, (Html.GetEnumSelectList<CalcModel.CalculationMethod>()))
            <input type="submit" />
```

Please tell me how to make a keyboard with numbers so that you don't have to enter it by hand.
Now i have three `labelFor` and `DropDownListFor` to select the method.

Comment: are you looking for some 'virtual' keyboard that is displayed under/next to your input? if so, you can use a javascript library/plugin i.e. something like this: https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Virtual-Keyboard-For-Input-Textarea-jkeyboard.html

Comment: Not really, I want to make a calculator similar to Windows

Answer (score -1):

> I want to make a calculator similar to Windows

You could use Bootstrap to display the number keyboards and the Calculation icon, then, use the [JavaScript eval() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) to calculate the result.

Sample code as below (refer [this link](https://codepen.io/centraleft/pen/gPrmLo)):

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <form class='form-group-lg form-inline' onsubmit='return false'>
            <input type='text' id='calcinput' class='focusedInput form-control'>
            <button type='submit' class='btn btn-warning btn-lg'>Clear</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-4'>
            <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' type='button'>7</button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-1'>
            <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' type='button'>8</button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-1'>
            <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' type='button'>9</button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-1'>
            <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' type='button'>+</button>
        </div>
    </div> <!--row-->
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-4'>
            <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' type='button'>4</button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-1'>
            <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' type='button'>5</button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-1'>
            <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' type='button'>6</button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-1'>
            <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' type='button' id='small'>-</button>
        </div>
    </div> <!--row-->
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-4'>
            <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' type='button'>1</button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-1'>
            <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' type='button'>2</button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-1'>
            <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' type='button'>3</button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-1'>
            <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' type='button' id='small'>*</button>
        </div>
    </div> <!--row-->
    <div class='row'>
        <!--row-->
        <div class='col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-4'>
            <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' type='button'>0</button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-1'>
            <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' type='button' id='small'>.</button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-1'>
            <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' type='submit' id='submit'>=</button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-1'>
            <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' type='button' id='small'>/</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the end of the above view page, add the following scripts:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.col-xs-1').click(function () {
                if ($(this).text().trim() !== '=') {
                    var text = $(this).text().toString()
                    $('input:text').val(function (i, val) {
                        return val + text.trim();
                    });
                }
            })
            $('.btn-warning').click(function () {
                $('input:text').val('');
            })
            $('#submit').click(function () {
                var expr = $('input').val();
                var res = eval(expr);
                $('input:text').val(res);
            })
        });
    </script>
}
```

The style file like this:

```
<style>
    .focusedInput {
        border-color: rgba(82,168,236,.8);
        outline: 0;
        outline: thin dotted \9;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6) !important;
    }

    body {
        background-color: gainsboro;
    }

    .form-inline {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .col-xs-1 {
        margin-right: 8px;
        margin-top: 44px;
    }

    #small {
        margin-left: 2px;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 56px;
        margin-bottom: 20px; 
    }

    .btn {
        font-family: Georgia;
        font-size: 22px
    }

    input {
        text-align: right; 
    }
</style>
```

Then, the result as below:

[image]

After that, if you want to save the calculate result into database, you could use JQuery to find the textbox value, then, use Ajax method to call the action method. You can refer the following links:

[JQuery AJAX and JSON Example in ASP.Net Core MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Core-jQuery-AJAX-and-JSON-Example-in-ASPNet-Core-MVC.aspx)

[How to use jQuery AJAX method to call an Action method in ASP.NET Core](https://www.yogihosting.com/jquery-ajax-aspnet-core/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this is written in pure js, but how can I do calculus in my controller in c #?

Comment: Hi @WarmingZ, I'm not sure why you vote down my reply, if you don't want to use this way, you can give me a comment, then, I will change the answer. So, in the view page, there still have two input text boxes to enter values, then send them to the controller? If that is case, after you click the number keyboard, you can get the selected value, and put them in your FirstNumber or SecondNumber text box. After that you can submit the form to action method or use JQuery Ajax to transfer the data to the action method.

Comment: Hey! Sorry, but I did not vote against your post. Yes, and I am deprived of the opportunity to vote

Comment: @WarmingZ, Okey, got it. So, in the view page, you still want to use two input text boxes to enter values, then send the value to the controller? If that is case, in the number keyboard click event, you can get the selected value, and put them in your FirstNumber or SecondNumber text box, then send them to controller.